# Why SQL variable still keep previous value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I notice a strange thing during doing some stored procedures 
I can explain that by the following example :

```
DECLARE @FileExtensionID int

SELECT * FROM FileExtensions WHERE (Name= 'pdf')
SELECT @FileExtensionID = ID FROM FileExtensions WHERE (Name= 'pdf')
SELECT IsNULL( @FileExtensionID , 0) -- First Select

SELECT * FROM FileExtensions WHERE (Name= '')
SELECT @FileExtensionID = ID FROM FileExtensions WHERE (Name= '')
SELECT IsNULL( @FileExtensionID , 0)-- Second Select
```

in the above queries i have a table called "FileExtensions" with ID ,Name columns and i try to set ID in variable @FileExtensionID, the problem that in the first select 
-`SELECT IsNULL(@FileExtensionID,0)`- @FileExtensionID have a vaild ID - for exmaple 9 -but in the second one when no row returned from

```
SELECT @FileExtensionID = ID FROM FileExtensions WHERE (Name= '')
```

it also still keep previous one - 9 - and not return 0 
i don't know why it happen so please could any tell me how it come ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a query returns no rows, the assignment `@FileExtensionID = ID` is not performed, which is why the variable still contains the value that was assigned earlier.

Answer (score 4):

Your second query doesn't return a row so it never gets assigned.

Make sure you "reset" the variable before each time you reuse it.

```
DECLARE @var int;
select @var = 3;

print @var;

select @var = 8 where 1=0; -- nothing happens

print @var;
```

Comment: should just add that the above example does not "reset" the variables. it just illustrates a simpler way of showing that zero rows makes the assignment @var = 8 not happen at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @FileExtensionID int

SELECT * FROM FileExtensions WHERE (Name= 'pdf')
SELECT @FileExtensionID = ID FROM FileExtensions WHERE (Name= 'pdf')
SELECT IsNULL( @FileExtensionID , 0) -- First Select

SET @FileExtensionID = NULL

SELECT * FROM FileExtensions WHERE (Name= '')
SELECT @FileExtensionID = ID FROM FileExtensions WHERE (Name= '')
SELECT IsNULL( @FileExtensionID , 0)-- Second Select
```

Your line `SELECT @FileExtensionID = ID FROM FileExtensions WHERE (Name= '')` will not overwrite `@FileExtensionID` if there are no results.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform a SELECT @Veraible = SomeField FROM SomeTable..., essentially it executes for each record returned from the SELECT.  So apparently the second SELECT (where Name = "") is returning no reocrds, so the @FileExensionID variable is never updated the second time around.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no matching row for criteria `Name = ''`, the variable will not be written over & hence it has its old value, with it.